# How to run created MSI in silent mode without CMD Msiexec command

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, silent-installer

How to implement MSI in silent mode (totally no UI) when user launch the msi setup ?

Comment: You mean to say that you do not want to use msiexec command from command prompt to begin installation. User will have to double-click the *.MSI file to begin installation and no UI should be shown instead during the install is in progress. Is that your requirement? In your title you have mentioned both `with` and `without` words which is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

The key is the **/QN switch** in the **[msiexec.exe command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx)**:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Installer.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

> ```
> /I = Run installer sequence
> /QN = Run totally silently
> /L*V = Verbose logging, log everything
> ```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to run the MSI in silent mode without using `msiexec` command from command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the msi in an (or call it from an) exe and pass msiexec /qn.

Comment: e.g. wix bootstrapper, but it will shows burn UI also. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifying the UI section in WiX will leave only the MSIExec's popup progress dialog. To get around that you would still need to execute from the command line.

More info [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Wix-Create-silent-MSI-using-Wix-td7588376.html)