# Remove or disable all MSI Installation UI in the process of the entire installation

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, basic-msi

I build a Basic MSI Project and got an install package(*.msi),then I want to disable all installation UI after I double click it, also I want it support overwrite install well, Anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904380/how-to-run-created-msi-in-silent-mode-without-with-cmd-msiexec-command

Comment: And another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806909/creating-a-silent-installer-for-a-msi

Comment: InstallShield has a bootstrapper too, just look around the docs.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache thank you!